# CFML/JS Creating nested JSON/Array from plain SQL

Tags: json, tree, coldfusion, nested, cfml

I would like to build a tree structre from a plain json array. 
The regular depth is approx. 6/7 (max 10) and has about 5,000 records.
My input json looks like this

```
[3,"01","GruppenAnfangHook",1,0,1,0,"Installationsmaterial",1.0,"",null,null,0.0,-1.0,null,803.0300,803.0300,0.00000,1,1]
[5,"01.001","JumboAnfangHook",3,0,3,0,"MBS Wandler 1.000",6.0,"St",null,null,0.0,-6.0,0.0000,336.7800,56.1300,0.00000,2,2], 
[38,"","ArtikelHook",3,5,3,0,"ASK 61.4 1000/5A 5VA Kl.1 Preis lt. Hr. K am 16.05.17",6.0,"stk",6.0,6.0,0.0,-6.0,null,21.5000,21.5000,0.00000,3,3]
```

But I need it structured with childrens like that

```
 {"0":34,1":"02.003",2":"JumboBegin","3":26,"4":0, "5":26,"6":0, "children":[
     {  "0":36,"1":"", "2":"Article","3":26,"4":34,"5":26,6:"0", 7: "Artikel"},
     {  "0":35,"1":"", "2":"JumboEnd",3":26,"4":34, "5":26, 6:"0",7:"Stunde"}
 ]}
```

My best approach so far was to build the child-structure with the following JS function in the frontend

```
function nest(data, parentId = 0) {
return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    let obj = Object.assign({}, e)
    if (parentId == e[4]) {
        let children = nest(data, e[0])
        if (children.length) obj.children = children
        r.push(obj)
    }
  return r;
}, [])}
```

It works well and fast (< 1s) with a small (<500) amount of records but my browser begins to freeze at 2,000 and above.

My thought was it is too much data and so I tried to solve it in the CFML backend.
Due to I'm new with recursion, Ben Nadels Blog helped me alot, so I used his post about recursion and created a working [example with sample data](https://trycf.com/scratch-pad/gist/b08b964d924444cbe52b1303ce6c15ee).

```
q = queryNew("id,grpCol,jumCol,leiCol,name,typ,order");
```

The grpCol is level 0, up to 5 groups can be placed in each other, in those groups can be placed two kinds of containers (jumCol and leiCol), they can be placed in each other to, but not in themselfs.

But now I am failing to convert it to a array of structures with child members. The structure of the HTML tree generated as output in the example is exactly what I want for my frontend JSON.
Because of the recursion I don't get, how to store it in an array outside of the function. 
My goal is a final return as serzializeJson(array).

Comment: Where is your source data coming from ? Is it from DB query. If yes then you use some returnformat options in cffunction tag.

Comment: The data is coming from a complex CTE and a select from MS SQL 2014, I need to join these tables in QoQ in CF .
The returnFormat is JSON from the original getter and my client-side approach. I don't see a lot more options there or what do you mean? 
I think I have to create a array of structs instead of outputting the html tree in my scratchpad example.

Comment: Seems your input is incomplete JSON type. So you should have some valid JSON format. The function can return different format(JSON,Array,Query,Struct etc ... ). Like we can return the data as you expected from the CF itself instead of jQUery. Hope you understand. And I'm sorry If I'm not clear more.

Comment: The JSON above is just a showcase, a working example with sample query is here [link](https://trycf.com/scratch-pad/gist/b08b964d924444cbe52b1303ce6c15ee)

Comment: Sometimes really large trees can be too much for a browser to handle no matter what. So you might consider lazy-loading the tree with ajax. *The data is coming from a complex CTE* What does the CTE look like? Also, which DBMS?